# Find where this series uniformly converges

Tags: real-analysis

Given the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n (1-x) \sqrt{n}$ find where it converges uniformly. I have proven that the series converges in an ordinary way in the $[0,1]$ segment by calulating the limit :

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x^n (1-x) \sqrt{n})=0$ This by using l'Hopital Rules.
Then when I do the def'n of uniform convergence I get :

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} sup{|x^n (1-x) \sqrt{n}|}=\sqrt{n}$ which is infinity.

Now after graphing $f_1,f_5,f_{100}$ from graph I get the impression that the problem is caused at $x=1$. I take an $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha| < 1 $ and after this the limit goes like this :
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} sup{|\alpha^n (1-\alpha) \sqrt{n}|}=\alpha^n (1-\alpha) \sqrt{n}$ which is $0$ by l'Hopital Rule.

Is my logic wrong here and if not how to aproach this problem when you don't have a graphin calculator . Thank You

Comment: Ok, sorry, I have not understood your question, I delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your different way of solution, it's always good to see not only one solution to problem but what really bothers me in my effort is the logic I have implemented this is what I really am interested in